Sparkline graph in a cel in google sheets
So i would like to get a stock price cheaker in my portfolio tracker on google sheets. to do so i have found this formula online but it does not seem to work. When building the sprakline chart, I get the message: Parameter 2 van functie SPARKLINE heeft een onjuiste grootte: kolom. Verwacht: 2. Huidig: 1. Which translates to Parameter 2 from function SPARKLINE has an incorrect size: column. Expected 2. Current: 1. Any
Idea how to solve this issue, I am already trying everything for 3 hours
the formula i use is  =(SPARKLINE(index(GOOGLEFINANCE(A6;"Price";VANDAAG()-364;VANDAAG());;2);{"Charttype";"column";"color";"purple"}))
i use ; because the area i live in. anny help would be greatly valued

I think the problem is your options array (the {...}) bit).  The docs for SPARKLINE say that the options array must be two-column (e.g. {"option1","value1";"option2","value2"}, but yours looks to be one-column {"option1";"option2"}.  I think the comma , is needed between option and value, while the semicolon ; is needed between each option/value pair.

Might be better-suited to SuperUser, since you are using an existing product, rather than developing code for a new one

Specific to Dutch localization, I believe the syntax is {"option1""value1";"option2""value2"}

Try adjusting the options in your sparkline like this:
{"charttype"\"column";"color"\"purple"}

The error is because the options should be an array of optional settings and their corresponding values. By using only ; to separate the items in the array, it is only a single column.
